# tabcontrol ownerdraw changes the tabcontrol's border style

Tags: c#, .net, tabcontrol, ownerdrawn

I got a problem with tabcontrol.
When I change the DrawMode to ownderdrawfixed, the borderstyle of the tabcontrol changes from "fixedsingle" to "3dfixed" but there's no such a property of tabcontrol borderstyle. the closest thing to borderstyle of tabcontrol is the appearance which didnt change.

[image]

look at the picture above to understand what I am talking about.

is there any way to change to color of the tabpage title without ownerdraw so I will not have to use ownerdraw?

or how can I fix the borderstyle of the tabcontrol?

Comment: Ownerdraw disables the visual styles renderer.

Comment: how can I enable it in ownerdraw?

Comment: @HansPassant , is there a way to do it without third-party libraries? I was hoping that I could do something like an `override` :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a control to ownerdraw, you are specifically saying "I will handle all drawing for this control".  This disables the visual styles rendering completely.

In order to render a control with visual styles, you'll need to use the facilities found in the [`System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafwxf9c.aspx) namespace.  It requires a good bit of code, but then you are saying you want to handle it all yourself.   I'd start with  the examples for [`VisualStyleRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx) - You'll need to call it, passing `VisualStyleElements` to render.

See also this question about treeview ownerdraw: [VisualStyleRenderer and themes (WinForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014816/visualstylerenderer-and-themes-winforms)

Comment: I got this function to draw the border I want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.tab.pane%28v=VS.90%29.aspx 
but I dont know how to use it. when I put DrawVisualStyleElementTabPane1(e) in the form's paint function it draw a new "control".