# How can obtain the image which uses windows 7 to draw the parent nodes in a treeview control?

Tags: delphi, winapi, custom-controls

I'm working in a custom control which mix two windows controls (listview and treeview). In some point, I need to draw the image which uses windows 7 (with themes enabled)  to identify the parent nodes, I'm using the [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the `TVP_GLYPH` part and the `GLPS_CLOSED` state (I tried with all the parts and states related to the `TREEVIEW` class without luck), but the result image  always is the *old* (+) or (-).

This image show the issue

[image]

I want to draw the *Arrow* image (inside of black circle) instead of the (+) sign (inside of orange circle).

This is the sample code which I use to draw the image.

```
uses
  UxTheme;

procedure TForm40.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iPartId : integer;
  iStateId: integer;
  hTheme  : THandle;
begin
  hTheme  := OpenThemeData(Handle, VSCLASS_TREEVIEW);

  iPartId := TVP_GLYPH;
  iStateId:= GLPS_CLOSED;          
  //iPartId := TVP_TREEITEM;
  //iStateId:= TREIS_NORMAL;
  if hTheme <> 0 then
    try
      
      //if (IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent(hTheme, iPartId, iStateId)) then
      //    DrawThemeParentBackground(Handle, PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle, nil);
      
      DrawThemeBackground(hTheme, PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle, iPartId, iStateId, Rect(0, 0, 31, 31), nil);
    finally
      CloseThemeData(hTheme);
    end;
end;
```

I check a couple of tools like the [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009701/windows-visual-themes-gallery-of-parts-and-states/4009712#4009712) made by [Andreas Rejbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282848/andreas-rejbrand) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/VisualStyleElementBrowser.aspx) too, but I can't find the image which I want.

My question is  : how I can obtain the *arrow* image?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer posted for [**Stigma**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207504/stigma) I found additional resources to the values of the parts and states of the `Explorer::Treeview` class.

- [`VisualStyleRenderer and themes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014816/visualstylerenderer-and-themes-winforms)
- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx?msg=3492581#xx3492581xx)

Comment: What is VSCLASS_TREEVIEW defined as?  Some quick googling seems to indicate you need to use "explorer::treeview" instead of just "treeview".

Comment: the `VSCLASS_TREEVIEW` is defined in the UxTheme unit, and is just a constant for the `TREEVIEW` value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, in the case of an ordinary `ListView` or `TreeView`, one can simply call [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on its handle to apply the proper sort of styling. The example from its MSDN page is as follows:

```
SetWindowTheme(hwndList, L"Explorer", NULL);
```

Since we are talking about a custom control, I am not so sure that applies here however. But since [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) causes the [`WM_THEMECHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to be sent to the proper window, it implies that you will just need to use the proper `OpenThemeData` call for the specific sub theme.

I think Luke's comment is correct. You probably just need to pass 'Explorer::Treeview' rather than the plain style. So, barring years of not having touched Delphi/Pascal:

```
hTheme  := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'Explorer::Treeview');
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set `SetWindowTheme(Handle, 'explorer', nil);` before painting to ensure that `OpenThemeData` will use new explorer style theme. Of course, window handle must be the same for both functions.

Comment: For what it's worth, I always call SetWindowTheme in an overriden CreateWnd so that the setting persists across window handle recreation.