# Windows Forms controls decoration

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I am new to C# and I am trying to build my own simplified Windows Explorer. I want to apply Windows theme to decorate treeview and listview. I cam accross this great [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014816/visualstylerenderer-and-themes-winforms), but have no idea how to attach these to my treeview. I am looking for detailed answer. As far, I understood only that I need to set DrawMode to OwnerDrawAll. What is next?

Comment: If I may make a suggestion: WinForms is on it's way out and there isn't any advantage to learning it before WPF. Anything that you want to do in WinForms can be done in WPF but not visa-versa and WPF just makes a lot more sense.

Comment: sorry, I do not know what is WPF and is link I gave related to WPF?

Comment: No your link isn't related to WPF. WPF is an alternative to WinForms. Here's a little bit of information about it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29294/Introduction-to-WPF

Comment: I think choice between WPF and WF is not related to question, any way, thx for your directions. Any thoughts about subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [solution](http://cyotek.com/blog/enabling-shell-styles-for-the-listview-and-treeview-controls-in-csharp), so next time someone will have easier way